# How can I get 100% fuel efficiency from an IC Engine in a car?

Tags: energy, heat-engine, efficient-energy-use

I understand that the current technology of internal combustion (IC) engines gives about 20% for a normal car.

I want to understand what I can do to achieve 100% or near 100% efficiency in the same engine for everyday practical use.

Comment: There is nothing you can do. The thermodynamic efficiency of an engine is limited by its thermodynamics, which is essentially fixed by the design. The newest Prius engine seems to achieve almost 40% and large ship diesel plants are said to be around 50% thermal efficiency. Improving efficiency beyond that point is difficult, even stationary power plants with multiple cycles (stages) of turbines and heat exchangers only manage around 60%. If we can use the exhaust heat for heating or industrial purposes (e.g. drying of solid fuels), 80-90% are in the realm of the possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The theoretical upper limit for the efficiency $\eta$ of a ["classical heat engine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine) (an IC engine falls into this category) is that of the [Carnot cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle):

$$\eta = 1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}$$

$100\%$ efficiency corresponds to $\eta=1$. $T_H$ and $T_C$ are the temperatures (in ${\rm K}$ or other absolute units) of the hot and cold reservoirs of the heat engine, respectively. In the case of your car engine, it's reasonable to take the outside temperature as the "cold" reservoir. I mean you could theoretically build a liquid helium bath into your car design, but it would evaporate pretty quickly (especially for a hot hot reservoir!) and wouldn't be at all practical. You can't really argue for a scheme where you refrigerate your engine, either, because this would require a second heat engine to do the refrigeration. So I'll assume $300\,{\rm K}$ for the cold reservoir. For the hot reservoir, you'd use something like the temperature of recently combusted gasoline vapors. I'll substitute a number that's easier to find, the melting point of steel, on the reasonable grounds that I want the engine to remain solid: about $1600\,{\rm K}$. This would give an efficiency of $81\%$. Can't reasonably do much better than that for a car engine, and you'll always do worse: an IC engine doesn't manage a perfect Carnot cycle, the hot reservoir is not actually that hot, there are mechanical losses in the system, etc. etc.

To get to true $100\%$ efficiency, you need either a $0{\rm K}$ cold bath, which in practice is impossible to maintain without active cooling, or an infinitely hot bath, which poses serious problems for the structural integrity of your vehicle.